# Sync data from api to wagtail

Tags: django, wagtail

I would like to create and update wagtail page making sync from `/api/` endpoint to wagtail page.

I made an example how to create, and it works. But with update, I have to change some logic. I tried to add a different primary key and use it to save the `id` from `API` but I got an error:

> Attempted to add a tree node that is already in the database

```py
def get_some_data():
    products = some_api_endpoint()
    product_page_content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Product)
    language_en = Language.objects.get(code="en")
    home_page_en = HomePage.objects.get(language=1)
    product_index_page_en = ProductsPage.objects.descendant_of(
        home_page_en
    ).first()
    for level_1 in products:
        for level_2 in level_1["general"]:
            # product_en, _ = Product.objects.update_or_create(
            #     id=level_2["id"],
            # )
            # product_en.language = level_2["id"]
            # product_en.title = level_2["name"]
            # product_en.draft_title = level_2["name"]
            # product_en.code = level_2["id"]
            # product_en.content_type=product_page_content_type,
            product_en = Product(
                # id=level_2["id"], # won't work, must be incremental
                language=language_en,
                title=level_2["name"],
                draft_title=level_2["name"],
                code=level_2["id"],
                content_type=product_page_content_type,
            )
            product_index_page_en.add_child(instance=product_en)
            product_en.save()
```

Comment: Why can't you use Django REST framework?

Answer (score 0):

Our project uses APIs to move data between sites. Our general approach is to save the primary key from the API in a field in our Page model. So in your example that would be something like `source_id` in your Product page model. Then in your loop, first check to see if you have a Product page with `source_id == level_2.id`. If you find a record, update fields in Product and do a normal `product_en.save()`. If you don't find a record, then use the code you have to create a record, `add_child`, and save.